# What is the direction of moment of inertia in a system?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia

Does [moment of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia) have a direction or is it just a property?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer is **NO**.

It is just a property of a body to resist the change in its angular velocity just like inertia which resists the change in linear velocity or more importantly State of rest or motion.

If it had a particular direction say anticlockwise, then a body  rotating in a clockwise direction will not need any external torque to come to a halt or speed up and the angular velocity will keep changing on itself while if it is rotating in the anticlockwise direction then it will need an external torque.

This is not what we experience in everyday life. So,  it is pretty clear that it has no preferred direction.

Hope it helps .

Answer (score 1):

**Does Mass has a direction?**

*Answer* is **NO**

You can percieve moment of inertia just like mass in a rotating system.

**To relate our study of simple translation kinetics with the rotational one it would be difficult if the term moment of inertia would not be proposed and you had to then study the rotating body microscopically using calculus.**

*Using moment of inertia we can study a rotating body macroscopically.*

Answer (score 0):

A body has a moment of inertia for any direction. $I=\sum_i m_i r_i^2$ where the $r_i$ are the perpendicular distances to the vector in the direction in question (though the centre of mass).  So if the $xy$ line in your plot were in a different direction, you would get a different value. You need to specify the direction when you talk about a moment of inertia. You will find this in the small print of examples and questions.

Answer (score 0):

The angular equivalent of Newton's second law is:

$$ \tau = I \alpha $$

where $I$ is the moment of inertia, $\tau$ is the torque and $\alpha$ is the angular acceleration. At first glance it looks as if $I$ is just a scalar, but it turns out to be more complicated that this. To see why consider rotating a disk about the $x$, $y$ and $z$ axes:

[image: Disk]

([image from Hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/tdisc.html))

Suppose we are rotating about the $z$ axis, so our torque is $(0, 0, \tau_z)$ and our angular acceleration is $(0,0, \alpha_z)$. Then we have:

$$ \tau_z = \tfrac12 MR^2 \alpha_z \tag{1} $$

And now we rotate about the $x$ axis, so our torque is $(\tau_x, 0, 0)$ and our angular acceleration is $(\alpha_x, 0,0)$. Then we have:

$$ \tau_x = \tfrac14 MR^2 \alpha_x \tag{2} $$

But we have a different moment of inertia in these two equations, so the disk clearly doesn't have a single moment of inertia. How can we handle this? Well what we do is write the moment of inertia as a matrix:

$$ \mathbf I = \begin{pmatrix} \tfrac14 MR^2 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && \tfrac14 MR^2 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && \tfrac12 MR^2 \end{pmatrix} $$

And our equation relating the torque and the angular acceleration becomes:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} \tau_x \\ \tau_y \\ \tau_z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \tfrac14 MR^2 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && \tfrac14 MR^2 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && \tfrac12 MR^2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \alpha_x \\ \alpha_y \\ \alpha_z \end{pmatrix} $$

I will leave it as an exercise for the reader to show that this gives us our equations (1) and (2) above when we rotate about the $z$ and $x$ axes.

So the moment of inertia is actually a matrix not a simple number or a vector. Specifically it is a second rank tensor called (unsurprisingly) [the inertia tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Inertia_tensor).

So the answer to your question is more complicated than you thought. The moment of inertia doesn't have a direction like a vector does, but it does depend on the direction of the rotation axis.